# data-structure for Key-value pair and state maintained in hyperledger fabric

Tags: data-structures, hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledger-fabric key value are maintained in such a way that each time value will be changed on the same key maintaining the version. How key value and version are maintained?

Here form the official documentation :

KVS operations are modeled as follows:
Put `(k,v)` for `k ∈ K` and `v ∈ V`, takes the blockchain state `s` and changes it to `s'` such that `s'(k) = (v,next(s(k).version))` with `s'(k') = s(k')` for all `k' != k`.

How the next version and the new value is maintained? It's in the linked list for each key or just one key maintain the value of data and version of state?

> In summary, my question is, how this data structure is modeled?

A diagrammatic explanation will be more preferable and more understandable.

Comment: There is a world state and then the ledger or Historian. The key exists on both. When a value is updated, the world state is updated, while the record of the update is added to the ledger. You can then query the historian with the key to find all previous values as it changed.

Comment: It's true, there is a case of versioning of the state, and we have only one key as per above representation of state data. We can't model mapping key with a value. There might be some data structure what actually hyperledger - fabric works. I didn't find any documentation to prove above semantics.  For easy way you can point me the code of hyperledger where exactly this mechanism has implemented.

Comment: https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-shim.HistoryQueryIterator.html Is the function to use. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/readwrite.html#transaction-validation-and-updating-world-state-using-read-write-set and https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/ledger.html should help you out with the concepts.

Comment: Somehow it works but not sufficient. thanks.